# Selecting default row if no rows return with join condition values from other tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, conditional-statements, default-value

I have two tables `ORDERS` and `RATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS
(   ID NUMBER(12,0), 
    DOW NUMBER(12,0), 
    COUNT NUMBER(12,0)
);

CREATE TABLE RATE
(   ID NUMBER(12,0), 
    DOW NUMBER(12,0), 
    RATE NUMBER(12,0)
);
INSERT INTO ORDERS (ID, DOW, COUNT) VALUES ('1', '1', '5');
INSERT INTO ORDERS (ID, DOW, COUNT) VALUES ('1', '3', '7');
INSERT INTO ORDERS (ID, DOW, COUNT) VALUES ('2', '1', '2');
INSERT INTO RATE (ID, DOW, RATE) VALUES ('1', '1', '10');
INSERT INTO RATE (ID, DOW, RATE) VALUES ('1', '2', '20');
INSERT INTO RATE (ID, DOW, RATE) VALUES ('1', '0', '50');
```

and I would like to get the costs of all the orders in table ORDERS, given that a default rate of 10 is used for those orders which do not have rates in the RATE table for the corresponding ids, and if an id is available in the RATE table, but no rate for a certain dow of that id is available, a default rate with dow 0 is always available for that id.

For the above example, the following would be expected:

```
id  dow   cost
--------------
1    1     50
1    3     350
2    1     20
```

Note that the 350 for id=1 and dow = 3 comes from count 7 multiplied by rate 50 for id=1 and dow=0, as there is no rate for id=1 and dow=3 in the table. I have tried the following with no luck:

```
SELECT o.id, o.dow, o.count*(coalesce(r.rate, 10)) as cost
FROM orders o
left join rate r
on r.id = o.id
and  r.dow = o.dow
;
```

and the following has compilation error:

> ORA-00904: "O"."DOW": invalid identifier
>
> 904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

```
SELECT o.id ,o.dow ,o.count * (coalesce(r.rate, 10)) cost
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, dow, rate
    FROM rate
    WHERE id = o.id
        AND dow = o.dow
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT id ,dow ,rate
    FROM rate
    WHERE id = o.id
        AND dow = 0
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM rate
            WHERE id = o.id
                AND dow = o.dow
            )
    ) r
    ON r.id = o.id
;
```

Can someone please help with the query?

Comment: i think 2 should be 100?

Comment: In the last SQL query you posted, try assigning an alias to the `rate` table as well. I'm guessing that the Oracle parser is not clever enough to handle one table with an alias and another table without an alias.

Comment: @EdBangga, id 2 does not have a rate, hence default rate, say 10, is used: 2*10 = 20.

Comment: @Abra, it does not work after adding alias to the `rate` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple `outer joins` with `RATE` table to fetch the desired result as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      O.ID,
>   3      O.DOW,
>   4      O.COUNT * COALESCE(R.RATE, RD.RATE) AS COST
>   5  FROM
>   6      ORDERS O
>   7      LEFT JOIN RATE R ON ( O.DOW = R.DOW )
>   8      LEFT JOIN RATE RD ON ( R.ID IS NULL
>   9                             AND RD.DOW = 0 )
>  10  ORDER BY O.ID;
>
>         ID        DOW       COST
> ---------- ---------- ----------
>          1          1         50
>          1          3        350
>          2          1         20
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Great! A second left join of the RATE table to fetch the default value when ID is matched but no rate for the DOW does the work. I made some minor changes to satisfy the original requirement: `SELECT
    O.ID,
    O.DOW,
    O.COUNT * COALESCE(R.RATE, RD.RATE, 10) AS COST
FROM
    ORDERS O
    LEFT JOIN RATE R ON ( O.ID = R.ID AND O.DOW = R.DOW )
    LEFT JOIN RATE RD ON ( O.ID = RD.ID AND RD.DOW = 0 ) 
ORDER BY O.ID;` Thank you @Tejash for the help!